# Minhas Builds de códigos sempre incorporam Python 2.7 ao invés do 3.6, como resolver?

Tags: python, cmd

Quando vou criar executaveis dos programas tenho sofrido com isso,e se alguém souber ajudar, eu agradeço.Segue a linha de comando que normalmente eu uso pra buildar no prompt.

> python 'nomedoarquivo'.py build

Comment: Na hora de compilar, a versão do Python usada é sempre a 2.7, quando o objetivo é compilar com a versão 3.6, o amigo lá em baixo já me esclareceu de usar o sufixo para especificar, porém, mesmo assim, se diz que o python3 não é reconhecido como programa interno.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O binário executável do `Python` versão 2.7 costuma não possuir sufixo:

```
$ python --version
Python 2.7.5
```

O binário executável do `Python` versão 3.x possui sufixo para evitar conflitos:

```
$ python3 --version
Python 3.4.5
```

Se você realmente que usar a versão 3 para fazer algo, use o executável correspondente.

Comment: Me esclareceu essa parte, porém, quando tento verificar a versão do python3 ou usá-la, se diz que: " 'python3' não é reconhecido como um comando interno ", mesmo eu o usando constantemente, o que posso fazer agora?

Comment: Que tal: https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.3/python-3.6.3.exe

Comment: Acho q entendi o problema, o Python 3 não estava no Path.